# Mini DisplayPort to DVI Dual-Link Adapter. Will it add some kind of latency?

Tags: graphics-card, display, dvi, adapter

I recently bought a 144hz / 1ms latency monitor with only a dvi connector for 144hz. My gaming laptop (hp omen 17-w201ns with gtx 1070) only have Mini Display Port connection.

I have read that you can connect both and still get 120hz 1920x1080 with this kind of adaptor --> Mini DisplayPort to DVI Dual-Link Adapter. [Apple one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Apple-MB571Z-Adaptor-DisplayPort-MacBook/dp/B001IF252C) should work?

My question is:
Will this adapter add some kind of extra latency? and if so, will it be noticeable if I do gaming with it?

Thank you.

Comment: You can find cheaper - [example](https://www.amazon.com/Tripp-Lite-DisplayPort-Converter-P137-06N-HDV4K6/dp/B074X6TJ6P/ref=sr_1_20?ie=UTF8&qid=1523617632&sr=8-20&keywords=%22Mini+DisplayPort%22+%22DVI+Dual-Link%22) at $37.96. Amazon has a good return policy.

Comment: I would say 'yes, it will add latency'. If it need to recalculate or propagate a signal it will always add some. The big question is if it adds enough to be noticeable. NO idea on that and thus no post as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mini DisplayPort (*same as DisplayPort but different size*) to DVI dual link adapters will work just fine, but only those really expensive **active adapters** ($100~).

**What is a active Mini-DP to DVI dual-link adapter?** (could be applied in many other adapters)

An active adapter (or powered adapter) it's a bit more complicated than a passive one. A passive one is *just* a cable that connects the computer to the monitor and it's limited to 60Hz only, like the HDMI. An active adapter is bigger (on the DVI port) because it have an extra chip who converts *signals* (can't find any better word).

Of course, the chip will need power, not provided by the Mini-DP port (supplied via AC adapter or USB connection).

**Why an active adapter needs extra power?**

A user on the Apple community in the official page of the adapter you reffered posted [this](https://www.apple.com/ca/shop/question/answers/product/MB571LL/A/does-the-mini-displayport-to-duallink-dvi-adapter-support-an-operating-frequency-of-120hz/Q7X4UFCT4A44UUHYT) and I'll quote:

> This extra power is required in order to properly amplify the video signal at 120Hz.

**Does the Mini-DP to DVI dual-link adapter (from Apple) works on 120Hz?**

Yes, see the link above.

**Will an active adapter** (*especifically the Apple one*) **add latency** (aka **input lag**)?

*Maybe*, I couldn't find an official source for that question but an user from `120Hz.net` posted [this](http://120hz.net/showthread.php?313-Displayport-gt-DVI-adapters-add-latency). I'll quote as well:

> My personal testing has revealed that my Apple mini-displayport to DVI adapter introduces lag of its own, as well as weird blocking.

The only way to know that is to try yourself. I can't be certain and many of us can't either.

Comment: This would be a better answer by providing a source for the claim that a non-active adapter `probably` adds latency.

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't have the time to dig deeper, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Any adapter that does conversion will introduce a lag.
For your specific question,
a user has published his test results in the post
[Displayport -> DVI adapters add latency](http://120hz.net/showthread.php?313-Displayport-gt-DVI-adapters-add-latency) :

> My personal testing has revealed that my Apple mini-displayport to DVI adapter introduces lag of its own, as well as weird blocking. It's perceptible when scrolling web pages when I have both monitors running at 2560x1440 with no scaling on the 30", with the display on the adapter always looking like it's catching up by a fraction of a second.
>
> Conclusion, if you're going with a multi-monitor setup, make sure your main or middle display is on the native dual-link DVI port off of your video card for the best possible experience.

As regarding Active versus Passive, they are usually differentiated by having
one power-line for Passive and two for Active.

Active was counseled for driving multiple monitors, because this requires
more power. It was never mentioned as having a better latency.

As today USB 3 delivers about double the power of USB 2,
to my thinking a "Passive" cable rated USB 3 should do just as well
as an "Active" two-cable rated USB 2.
"Older" technology (VGA, DVI, HDMI) have a higher current deliverance
requirement than DP, so may in the past have required an "Active" adapter
with two power cables.

My best advice would be to get a modern adapter that does high resolutions,
no matter whether it has one or two power cables, so is likely built using
the latest technology.
It does not have to be in the $100+ range.
Get it from a distributor such as Amazon, which has a good return policy,
just in case its lag is unbearable.
An example might be
[this adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B074X6TJ6P)
which currently sells for $37.96.