# Mini DisplayPort to DVI-D (dual link) connection issue

Tags: dvi, mini-displayport

- My laptop, Macbook Air mid-August 2013, has a Mini DisplayPort.
- I have a LCD with DVI-D (dual link) connector.

I am trying to connect my laptop to my LCD, using a **Mini DisplayPort to DVI adapter** (not [mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter](https://www.apple.com/sg_smb_5200/shop/product/MB571Z/A/mini-displayport-to-dual-link-dvi-adapter)) but the LCD is not detected by the Mac OS. The adapter's DVI side is DVI-D (dual link) connector to be precise. How can I connect my laptop with this LCD.

I have tried the connection using two cables available in my home. One is DVI-D (single link) and the other is DVI-D (dual link). None worked.

The below two points are for extended context, if that help in understanding the issue.

**Point # 1.** A Youtube video recommended to connect everything as expected (laptop -> adapter -> cable -> LCD) and restart the mac and close the lid immediately. According to the video, the OS will try to 'force' the video output to the attached LCD. By following this advice, I can only see the system rebooting loading bar which stops at one point.

**Point # 2.** I have another older Samsung LCD at home, with lower resolution. This LCD has DVI-D (dual link) connector. I can successfully attach this LCD to my laptop, using the previously mentioned adapter.

P.S.
Monitor is qnix qx2710led.

Comment: After reading [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1313694/257754) on a relevant, but not similar, question, I think my situation has something to do with Active vs Passive adapters. But not sure!

Comment: You told us what adapter you aren't using but not which you **are**. Also, you included no details on the monitor itself. Do you know if the MacBook is even capable of driving it?

Comment: @Tetsujin I told which adapter I am using. Read my 1st line, after two bullet points.